# What should I worry about after installing Magento CE

Tags: ecommerce, performance, magento, system, qa

I am currently managing a project of Magento CE new build (to replace a Woocommerce) on a UNIX system, provided to me by Digital Ocean.

My friends keep saying that Magento is a performance killer, yet, it's supreme eCommerce features make me use it and pay the system administration "price". Before installation, I want to prepare to performance issues so there won't be problems. What problematic indicators should I look for while monitoring and QAing this system, as a webmaster?

Comment: Entire books have been written about Magento.   A proper answer to this question is book sized rather than the few paragraphs that would fit here.